# How can i stretch a PageView to fit the height of a RadWindow?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have a RadPageView which I use with a RadMultiPage and RadTabStrip inside of a RadWindow. The problem is that my RadPageView does not stretch to fill the RadWindow. I set the Height and Width to 100%, and for the Width it works fine... (when I resize the window, the PageView is also resized). However, the height of the PageView only stretches down to the height of the controls that it contains. I spent a lot of time playing with the properties trying to get this to work... Is there an easy way to achieve this? Or do I have to handle client side OnResize events... It works for the width though.. shouldn't it be easy to also work for the height?

[image: PageView1]

[image: PageView2]

Answer (score 1):

You may want to assign a CSS class to the RadPageView, and apply the height to that CSS class.    If you created a class like .PageView { height: 100%; } and assign this class to each page view, that would probably work because each page view is its own element and doesn't necessarily stretch out of the box.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Brians answer is correct. One more information about this.
sometimes you have to care in telerik about css styling.
They will sometimes ignore your styles until you add

```
!important
```

on the CSS style. This will override the teleriks own styles. meaning:

```
.PageView { height: 100% !important; }
```

best regards, noone.